# VBA XAxis Data Labels Issue

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have a piece of code that dynamically works out a range in Excel and plots them into a graph. This works fine, however, I'm building a similar report for another team and have lifted the same piece of code and the data labels on the X Axis will not populate. I was wondering if any one might have any ideas? I have tried the code a number of times, it works in the old but not in the new, so I'm now wondering if its not the VBA code but maybe the chart settings in Excel. Again I have looked but can't see anything obvious. Any help would be much appreciated.

Code below:

```
With Sheets("DynamicCharts")
    LastRow = .Range("AL" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Set Rng1 = .Range("AL2:AL" & LastRow & ", AO2:AO" & LastRow)
    Set Rng2 = .Range("AM2:AM" & LastRow)
End With

With Sheets("Hazard Details").ChartObjects("WS_Ground").Chart
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .SetSourceData Source:=Rng1
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Values"
    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .Values = Rng2
        .AxisGroup = 2
        .Name = "Locs"
    End With
End With
```

The data looks like this:

[image]

The original output looks like this:

[image]

However the same code, new chart is giving me this:

[image]

I just can't work out why I'm getting 1,2,3 when Rng1 is including column AL which is the range names. Which works in a previous sheet, which is exactly the same. Any ideas or advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

P.S. Just to add if I click in 'Select Data' in the chart I see this, so still can't understand why they aren't labelling this up properly:

[image]

Comment: For second series you have mentioned values as `.Values = Rng2` but not the category `Range("AL2:AL" & LastRow)` .. May be that is causing the problem.